# bashrc issue in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, ns2

I updated my .bashrc with following text to run ns2 and saved it.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/nsallinone-2.34/bin:/home/user/ns-allinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/unix:/home/user/ns-allinone-2.34/tk8.4.18/unix
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/ns-allinone-2.34/otcl-1.13:/home/user/ns-allinone-2.34/lib
export TCL_LIBRARY=/home/user/nsallinone-2.34/tcl8.4.18/library
```

Now when i run my Cygwin, each time it displays error as:

```
-bash: $'\r': command not found
```

Even now i have removed the above text but it still gives error.

Do i have to recompile ./bashrc, if I have how i will do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when i run my Cygwin, each time it displays error as:
>
> -bash: $'\r': command not found

It seems that you edited your `.bashrc` using an application that added `CR` to the file.

Running `dos2unix` would remove the CR:

```
dos2unix /path/to/.bashrc
```

Comment: I used wordpad, so which editor should i use to update .bashrc?

Comment: @user3035037: Why didn't you use ms-word to edit it? :P Jokes apart, use gvim/vim on Windows